# backbone confusion on collections and model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

There's a folder of js/collections/contact.js and it has only

```
ContactManager.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: ContactManager.Models.Contact
});
```

The demo of a small app : http://dmytroyarmak.github.io/backbone-contact-manager/#contacts

I'm trying to guess what does it do, but have no clue so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only creates a new collection type and demonstrate how to encapsulate each component of an app. This project uses the global object `ContactManager` as a kind of namespace for the app.

The collection is used [here](https://github.com/dmytroyarmak/backbone-contact-manager/blob/0159ff31725252f1a04451c297258e17872a4a01/app/js/app.js#L7):

```
var contacts = new ContactManager.Collections.Contacts(data.contacts),
```

And is equivalent to:

```
var contacts = new Backbone.Collection(data.contacts, {
    model: ContactManager.Models.Contact
});
```

Which mean each object inside `data.contacts` is made into a `ContactManager.Models.Contact` model object.

Additional documentation:

- [Backbone's collection model property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model).
- [Creating your own collection with `.extend(...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-extend)

Comment: for me it sounds like assing contact to model to collection

Comment: @SunnyHo it's kind of that, the collection puts raw object `{ id: "1", data: "example" }` into new Backbone model instances and keeps them inside its `models` array.